# C++ ofstream writing variables into a text file

Tags: c++, file

I wasn't able to find any obvious answers to this, and I'm pretty stumped.

Do I need to do something different when I want to write a variable string into a text document compared to what I need to do when I want to write just a set string into said document?

This code would properly write "set string" on 8 individual lines on newfile.txt (and create it).

```
string output_file = "newfile.txt"
ofstream file_object_2;
        file_object_2.open(output_file, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        string nextline;
        for (int i = 0; i <= row_number; ++i)
        {
            file_object_2 << "set string" << "\n";
        }
        file_object_2.close();
        return 0;
```

But this would leave the file completely empty, even if line_vector[i] itself has strings within it (and cout can print them)

```
string output_file = "newfile.txt"
ofstream file_object_2;
        file_object_2.open(output_file, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        string nextline;
        for (int i = 0; i <= row_number; ++i)
        {
            nextline = line_vector[i];
            file_object_2 << nextline << "\n";
        }
        file_object_2.close();
        return 0;
```

I tried to look at the documentation and do it the same way as they had done, but I'm having no success here. Obviously because of my own failure, but I just can't figure out where I'm in the wrong here.

The only difference with those two codes are in the lines where I'm trying to write into the document

```
file_object_2 << nextline << "\n";
```

vs

```
file_object_2 << "set string" << "\n";
```

main() that I tried to trim down so it has less dynamic functionality (no manual inputs) but still does not work:

The text file "a.txt" has just a couple of lines of random strings

```
[a.txt]
("Yogi has a best friend too
Boo Boo, Boo Boo
Yogi has a best friend too
Boo Boo, Boo Boo Bear
Boo Boo, Boo Boo Bear
Boo Boo, Boo Boo Bear
Yogi has a best friend too
Boo Boo, Boo Boo Bear")
```

And the function itself

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>


    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        string input_file = "a.txt";

        vector<string> line_vector;

        string output_file = "output.txt";

 // reads from the original text file. Included in the example because I might
 // be constructing the vector in a stupid way and this is where it happens
            int row_number = 0;
            string line;
            while (getline(file_object, line) )
            {
                cout << line << endl;
                line_vector.push_back(line);
                ++row_number;
            }
            file_object.close();


  // writing onto a new file starts, this is where I'd assume the problem is
            ofstream file_object_2;
            file_object_2.open(output_file, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
            string nextline;
            for (int i = 0; i <= row_number; ++i)
            {
                nextline = i + " " + line_vector[i];
                file_object_2 << nextline << "\n";
            }
            file_object_2.close();
            return 0;    
    }
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please. Your code looks just fine.

Comment: Missing a [MCVE]. Are you sure you aren't doing `line_vector[line_vector.size()]`? Check the comparison...

Comment: Alright, give me a second to get the whole bit

@logicstuff I tried writing only "i" to the text document as well but had no success, and was able to print out line_vector[i] fine to the console using `cout << line_vector[i]`

Comment: That does not rule out *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Added the code now. Does undefined behaviour mean that I might've left too vague commands and C++ translates them differently than I'm intending and that causes problems?

Comment: @Grak - Undefined Behaviour means that if you write *any* code that is not correct according to the C++ standard then your entire program is invalid and may do *anything* - no guarantees on *any* behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broken:

```
i + " " + line_vector[i]
```

You meant `to_string(i) + " " + line_vector[i]`, but you used `+` directly on `i` and `""`, which the compiler determines is `operator+(int, const char*)` which is pointer arithmetic, not a conversion of `i` to a string.  Since the string in question only has one character (a NUL), adding `1` number results in a past-the-end pointer which can't be dereferenced, adding larger numbers is already undefined behavior.

The simplest fix would be to keep `i` separate from `nextline`, and write it to the file directly.  Your loop body becomes:

```
{
   nextline = line_vector[i];
   file_object_2 << i << " " << nextline << "\n";
}
```

But it should also work to convert `i` to a string using `std::to_string()`.

---

As a side note, the first snippet of code you claimed is broken (where `nextline = line_vector[i];`) actually is just fine.  If you had bothered to test that you might have found the problem yourself.

Comment: I did test out `nextline = line_vector[i];`, I also tested out `file_object_2 << i << "\n";`and still got nothing (though that might be caused by the fact that i was acting as an int?)

Comment: @Grak: You must have made a mistake when testing those, since they are ok.  Sure you didn't try something like `nextline = i + "\n"; file_object_2 << nextline;` ?  The little differences between your code and your summaries are where the actual errors lie.

Comment: When I was trying only `nextline`, I hadn't even incorporated `i` into it yet, but you're absolutely right that I had made a goof (or numerous) somewhere down the line as now it works. Thanks for sticking with me